# Anti-derivative of $\frac{\sqrt{2+5x+5x^2+x^3}}{x(x+1)}$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the ODE
$$\Vert f \Vert^2 = A(x)$$
$$\Vert f' \Vert^2 = B(x)$$
where $f$ is a vector function of $\mathbb{R}^m$ ($m$ unknown) and $A$, $B$ two rational fractions. I tried to look for a solution of the form

$$f(x) = \sqrt{A(x)}\left(\begin{array}{c}\cos F(x)\\\sin F(x)\end{array}\right)$$

Since $\Vert f'\Vert^2$ is $A'(x)^2+F'(x)^2A(x)^2$, I end up with the following equation (replacing $A$ and $B$ by their values)

$$F'(x)^2 = \frac{2+5x+5x^2+x^3}{8x^2(1+x)^2}$$

I'm having trouble moving forward from here. Can you think of a way to find $F$ ?
If you want to experiment another way, we have

$$A(x) = \frac{(1+x)}{2x} \qquad \mathrm{,} \qquad B(x) = \frac{4+x+x^2}{16x^3}$$

Comment: seems you forgot something $F'^2=\frac{AB-A'\ ^2}{A^2}=\frac {-70x^2-91x-28+x^3}{8(1+x)^2x^2}$ but it's not so much better...

Comment: What kind of norm is this? The standard Euclidian norm? If $f$ is a vector function how are you supposed to determine its $m$ components if you only have two equations? Or do you have a scalar function $f$ that is depending on $m$ variables? The Integral that you want to carry out seems not to have a simple closed form. You need to better define your problem statement. For example for $f(x)$ being a scalar function the second equation specifies an additional constraint that cannot be fulfilled for any combinations of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: So it seems the existence of solutions depends on the particular choice of $A$ and $B$

Comment: Actually that problem is a "simpler" form of another harder one, where you have more equations and still $m$ unknown. Since I only kept two equations here, I tried to find $f$ using this particular form with $m$ being $2$.
The norm is indeed the standard Euclidian norm.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that there is no typo in $(2+5x+5x^2+x^3)$ ?

If the question comes from a textbook exercise, it is quite sure that there is a typo.

If not, my y proposal is :

Solve $\quad 2+5x+5x^2+x^3=0\quad$ for $x$. The roots are : $a\,,\,b\,,\,c$ , (one real and two complex). Rewrite the integral as :
$$\int\frac{\sqrt{2+5x+5x^2+x^3}}{x(x+1)}dx=\int\frac{\sqrt{(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)}}{x(x+1)}dx$$

This is an integral of elliptic kind : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegral.html

Sorry, I will not give the details of calculus. It should be too long and tiresome. Moreover, if there is a typo as supposed above, it should be a waste of time. WolframAlfa can do it faster and better : http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sqrt%28%28x-a%29%28x-b%29%28x-c%29%29%2F%28x%28x%2B1%29%29

[image]

The special functions $E$ , $F$ and $\Pi$ are the basic Incomplete Elliptic functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, there was actually a typo I think, it should be $2+5x+2x^2+x^3$ but there's still no "simple" root.
This equation popped up in a research problem so it's not expected to work as fine as a textbook problem unfortunately.

Comment: OK. I understand the context. I am afraid the analytic solution is complicated. WolframAlfa give an awful result : http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sqrt%282%2B5x%2B2x%5E2%2Bx%5E3%29%5C%28x%28x%2B1%29%29 I think that the method cited in my main answer is convenient, but difficult to apply in practice. For practical application, I would prefer numerical calculus (numerical tools for integration).